# Shell script to kill processes except those owned by user

Tags: awk, scripting, process, kill, ps

I am Looking for some help in creating a script to kill processes, but return an error message if they are owned by root. Firstly I would like to say that I am a total beginner at this. At the moment I currently have: kill `ps -aef | grep $1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` Which works ok to kill a process name taken as an argument. but I cant get it work as an if statement, to stop it from killing a process if the the owner is root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pgrep -u 0 "$1" && echo "Can't kill process: Owned by root" || killall "$1"
```

The `pgrep -u 0` will only search for processes owned by `UID 0` (root). If the process isn't found (so its either not existing or not running as root), prgep will return a non-zero return code and the `killall` command will be executed. If prgrep returns a zero return code, the echo will be executed, but not the killall command.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ps -aef | grep $1 | egrep -v grep | awk '$1 != "root" {print $2}'
```

the statement `$1 != "root"` will filter out process own by root. You might still get error on daemon process (e.g. `www-data` if you are running apache).